Krita Print Resolution PPI and Blender X/YResolution Mismatch Possibly Affecting Displacement Map UV Alignment
Issues
One issue I have is that the ppi value of the displacement maps are reported differently by Krita and Blender. This is curious.
Another issue I’m having is that while most of the faces are displacing as I anticipate, some of them are affected or unaffected in confusing ways. This is serious.
I have figured out how to accomplish my initial goal, so the 2 questions at the end of this post are made in the hope of understanding the irregular displacement and not how to circumvent it.
Further Details
I am working on a Blender project where I apply a sequence of 24 *.png files as displacement maps to a cube on a timeline of 24 frames. The cube has 7 subdivisions per side. I am applying a displacement modifier to this cube and selecting an image sequence as the source of displacement data. There is one *.png file for each frame. The *.png files are painted in such a way that the sequence of displacement maps should create a looping animation.
I noticed some irregularities with the reported resolution (ppi – pixels per inch) of the file I created in Krita. Using Krita, a file of dimension 26x, 26px, 100 ppi was generated, though when saved as *.png file and reopened, the dimensions in Krita’s Image Properties tab appeared as such 26px, 26px, 99.999627 ppi.
That same file I made when opened an applied as a displacement map in in Blender has it’s dimensions reported as XResolution 99.9998 and YResolution 99.9998.
When I started this project I had read that displacement maps displaced faces, and so I made a displacement map in Krita where one pixel would be mapped exactly to one face in Blender and so displace that face. To make sure of this, I made very low resolution images in Krita, and then each vertex has been snapped to the edge of a pixel in the UV Editor of Blender. I now believe, after much experimentation that in Blender vertices are what are actually displaced and that faces are only displaced as a result of that. That being said, many of the vertices were displaced as I thought they would be and so I’m still trying to understand the irregularity that is happening here.

Notice how in the top image most vertices are displaced by the red pixels that they border, though that in the bottom image that statement is less true. Notice also in the top image on the right side, how the opposite horizontal edges of the displaced shape are differently interpreted.

Question 1.
Why is there a difference between the values reported by Krita and Blender?
Question 2.
Why are the vertices affected in the way where many of them appear to be affected by the red edges of pixels, though not consistently? Do the slightly different resolutions reported by Blender and Krita have any significance? If Blender is to be trusted, each vertex of the cube is snapped to the corners of pixels of a very low resolution displacement map, some of which have 2 different colour values. How does Blender interpret this?

On question 1: why do you care for ppi? The ppi (pixels per inch) are usually completely irrelevant and basically dependent on your monitor. Both resolutions 99.999627 and 99.9998 are approximately 100 ppi, so I would guess if you have a full HD monitor with a resolution of 1920×1080 pixels, it is a 22" monitor. And for question 2: The displacement can only move vertices, there is nothing inbetween which can be moved. Between a high vertex and adjacent low vertex, the only connection is a straight edge. The image has a certain amount of pixels, and the values are clearly defined per pixel.

Vertices in the UV map however can have any position as precise as Blender allows for float values, between (0, 0) and (1, 1) when within the map and any other value positive or negative outside. Displacement then tries to interpolate values, and depending on texture and mesh the result might not be as expected. The best to get the displacement closest to the texture it is based on is having a high res mesh (the more vertices with less distance between them, the more exact the result) or switch the Feature Set in the Render Properties to Experimental and use Adaptive Subdivision.

@GordonBrinkmann thanks for the reply. The reason I might care about the ppi is that I can't see why it is happening. Blender is a complex beast. Krita also has its quirks. They're great tools though and I'm trying to understand them better. At present, I'm puzzled and trying to do something about that.

Regarding my monitor. I have 2, one at 1920x1080 and another at 2560x1440. Does that have any bearing on the numbers 99.999627 and 99.9998? I'll also try that Adaptive Subdivision feature and see what happens, thanks.

The ppi value is the pixel density of your monitor, how many pixels fit into one inch. So it is not really dependent on if the monitor has 1920×1080 or 2560×1440. A phone with 6" display at 1920×1080 has about 367 ppi, a 30" with 2560×1440 only 98 ppi. I do not know if the software draws the information from the monitor driver or other hardware data (or just guesses?), but just the image itself has no real ppi. Even if you zoom the image to 50%, the ppi does not double, because the monitor just displays it with half the width and height and so half the amount of X pixels and half the Y pixels.
